# I have XML parsing response in Android how do i want to implement JSON parse on that xml response it's possible?

Tags: android, json, xml

I have XML parsing response in Android ,on that i want to implement JSON parse on that xml response it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question you want to parse `XML` to `JSON` and if that is the case you can use  `JAVA-JSON` library check it out at [GITHUB](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java).

Quick example

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(XML_STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use json-lib, a library which adds JSON support to any Java program. json-lib can take XML and convert it into a JSON object.

[Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Eg.

```
String xml = "your xml string";                
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
JSON json = xmlSerializer.read( xml );
```